# How to wait for multiple futures to complete in Vapor Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

I am trying to figure out how to wait for multiple Futures to complete.
I know how to asynchronously wait for them with: 
`summaryFuture.whenSuccess {}` but that just handles one case. I need to wait for both summaryFuture and sponsorFuture to finish, then work with both before sending back a Response.

```
  let summaryFuture = client.post(summaryURL) { post in
        post.http.headers.add(name: "authtoken", value: token)
        }.flatMap(to: SummaryModel.self) { (response) in
            return try response.content.decode(SummaryModel.self)
    }

  let sponsorEnrollerFuture = client.post(sponsporEnroller) { post in
        post.http.headers.add(name: "authtoken", value: token)
        }.flatMap(to: SponsorEnrollerModel.self) { (response) in
            return try response.content.decode(SponsorEnrollerModel.self)
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use either `.and` or `.flatten`

For `.flatten` your futures should return `Void`, so the end result will be `Future<Void>` as well.

`.and` may be used like this

```swift
let summaryFuture = client.post(summaryURL) { post in
    post.http.headers.add(name: "authtoken", value: token)
}.flatMap(to: SummaryModel.self) { (response) in
    return try response.content.decode(SummaryModel.self)
}

let sponsorEnrollerFuture = client.post(sponsporEnroller) { post in
    post.http.headers.add(name: "authtoken", value: token)
}.flatMap(to: SponsorEnrollerModel.self) { (response) in
    return try response.content.decode(SponsorEnrollerModel.self)
} 

// Now combine the two futures
return summaryFuture.and(sponsorEnrollerFuture).map { summary, sponsorEnrolled in
    print("summary: \(summary)")
    print("sponsorEnrolled: \(sponsorEnrolled)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I figured it out.

To wait for multiple *Futures* to complete, you have to use `.add`. In my particular case.

```
 let summaryFuture = client.post(summaryURL) { post in
        post.http.headers.add(name: "authtoken", value: token)
        }.flatMap(to: SummaryModel.self) { (response) in
            return try response.content.decode(SummaryModel.self)
    }

  let sponsorEnrollerFuture = client.post(sponsporEnroller) { post in
        post.http.headers.add(name: "authtoken", value: token)
        }.flatMap(to: SponsorEnrollerModel.self) { (response) in
            return try response.content.decode(SponsorEnrollerModel.self)
    } 

  // Now combine the two futures
 let multipleFutures = summaryFuture.add(sponsorEnrollerFuture)

 // Now I can use
 mutipleFutures.whenSuccess = {(summary, sponsorEnroller) in ...}
```